# Why was my highly up-voted question with several highly up-voted answers suddenly deleted? (69 up votes total)

Tags: discussion

The following posts (and all of their reputation?) was all deleted on 08-Aug-2018, two months after all of the activity. This all happened on the one question linked below.

1. Why?
2. Why *two months later?*
3. Why isn't there a reason stated there for us to see?
4. This deletion does not show up on my recent deleted question page. Is this kind of deletion in fact silent and undetectable by me within the SE UI?
5. Besides all of the work becoming inaccessible to future readers, and least important, how much reputation was removed by this deletion? Was the 60+ day delay before deletion meant to preserve reputation? (those -100's and -200's would have raised some eyebrows.)

Votes and work done on this post

```
Question:  +20/-1    11-June-2018
Answer:    +11-/1    11-June-2018
Answer:    +28/-1    11-June-2018
Answer:     +4/-0    12-June-2018
Answer      +2-/0    12-June-2018
Answer      +3/-0    18-June-2018
Answer      +1/-0    12-June-2018
Answer      +0/-0    12-June-2018
```

There is one answer with -4 votes that was immediately self-deleted on 12-June-2018, only 20 hours after it was posted, so that can't be the reason.

A search of recent news will show that interest in searching for liquid salt water (brine) continues to if anything, increase with time.

- Science: 03-August-2018  [Radar evidence of subglacial liquid water on Mars](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/361/6401/490)
- EarthSky.org: 28-Sept-2018 [Pink lagoon provides clues to possible Mars life](http://earthsky.org/space/pink-lagoon-spain-shows-extremophile-microbes-life-on-mars)
- Space.com: 25-July-2018 [Mars' South Pole May Hide a Large Underground Lake](https://www.space.com/41272-mars-liquid-water-below-ice-cap.html)
- Science News: 18-August-2010 [Mars (probably) has a lake of liquid water](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/mars-may-have-lake-liquid-water-search-life)

**Deleted Question:** [Is there any economical way to move the water from the Martian poles to the people?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27785/12102) currently only visible to users with 10k+ rep.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the question was flagged and deleted without extremely careful review. Looking at it closer, I have undeleted it.

Reputation is preserved after something is deleted after a lengthy period of time.

Comment: Can I ask what the flag was?

Comment: It was related to the JP Morgan comment

Comment: okay thank for the partial but very speedy answer! Does the question look okay currently?